# wxMaxima: what kind of object is created by substituting a string into a function?

Tags: maxima

Given

```
f(x):=3*x^2;
a:f("alpha");
```

What kind of object is `a`? I tried testing with `stringp` and `symbolp` and anything similar I could find (though I couldn't find a comprehensive list).

I also used `to_lisp()` to run `(inspect $a)` but Maxima just hung. When I stopped it, it said that it was a "proper list of length 3" but `listp(a)` comes back false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maxima is happy to evaluate functions with string arguments instead of symbols, and the result an ordinary Maxima expression. You can see that via `grind(a)` which will show `"alpha"` in the place of `x`.

Maxima can do some operations on expressions which contain strings instead of symbols, e.g. `"foo" + "foo"` simplifies to `2*"foo"`, and you can say `subst("foo"=123, <whatever>)` to replace "foo" with a value. However, a string cannot have a value, so `"foo": 123` fails. Also, strings cannot have properties.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I was writing a function that distinguishes the handling based on the type of object. Up until now, it had worked because everything was either a string or a number (so I had clauses with `stringp` and `numberp`. I've worked-around the issue by passing it to an `else if not(stringp(a)) then a: tex1(a)` but it didn't seem like the tidiest handling (I'm also still not clear as to what kind of object Maxima considers `a` to be).

Comment: Maxima considers `a` is just an ordinary expression. For better or worse, Maxima doesn't have a specific test for it (e.g. putatively `expressionp`). The closest would be `not atom(a)` where `a` is whatever needs to be tested. However, note that atoms comprise symbols in addition to strings and numbers. There might be other wrinkles.